# Como hacer Sticky el footer en materialize?

Tags: html, css, materialize

hice todo como me los explicaban en la pagina de materialize.

```
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
```

Sin embargo no me funciona ya que no me pone el footer hasta el fondo.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código completo en tu pregunta?. Dale clic en [edit]. se necesita mas código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es el siguiente, en la documentación de Materialize apartado footer indica lo siguiente:

utilizamos flexbox para estructurar nuestro html de modo que el pie de página esté siempre en la parte inferior de la página. Es importante mantener la estructura de su página dentro de las 3 etiquetas HTML5: HEADER, MAIN, FOOTER

Lo que indica que debes usar header para tu menú o lo principal de tu página.

Main para tu cuerpo del contenido.

y Footer para el pie de Página.

debes de tener la etiqueta MAIN indispensablemente para que el sticky footer se pueda aplicar.

Te dejo un ejemplo basico con código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
     <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

     <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
</head>

<body>
<style>
        body {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
</style>

<header>
    <h1>Cabezera</h1>
</header>
<main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam cumque inventore nisi deleniti reiciendis voluptatum delectus molestias sunt. Debitis ex nihil ipsa nemo ullam. Omnis aut consequatur id excepturi rem!</p>
</main>

    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col l6 s12">
                    <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
                    <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer
                        content.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
                    <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
                © 2014 Copyright Text
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->

    <script>
        M.AutoInit();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En una implementación con reactjs tienes que dejar el  component asi:

```
App.js......................................................................
import React from 'react';
import Navegation from './components/Navigation'
import Casos from './components/Casos'
import Estudiantes from './components/Estudiantes'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import './App.css'

import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {

  return (
   <Router>
     <header>
     <Navegation/>
     </header>
      <main>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Casos}/>
      <Route path="/casos" exact component={Casos}/>
      <Route path="/estudiantes" exact component={Estudiantes}/>
      </main>
      <footer>
      <Footer/>
      </footer>

   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Ahora en la css  que por lo general se llama index.css agregas lo siguiente tal como en la documentacion de materilize solo que con un cambio el body por #root el selector de nuestro componente

```
#root {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
```

OJO que hay que cambiar body por #root y listo